# Binomial or something else?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Players A and B take turns in answering trivia questions, starting with player A answering the first question. Each time A answers a question, she has probability $p_1$ of getting it right. Each time B plays, he has probability $p_2$ of getting it right.

Suppose that the first player to answer correctly wins the game (with no predetermined maximum number of questions that can be asked). Find the probability that A wins the game.

Can someone post step-by-step solution? This is a question from Joe Blitzstein's Stat 110 homework question

Comment: $\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2}$ i guess

Comment: @Dror Can you explain it step-by-step?

Comment: @Dror: that does not take account of A answering first.  Try $\frac{d_1}{d_1+d_2-d_1d_2}$

Comment: How'd you get that?

Comment: @Henry I understand, but there is no end to the nuances you can pile up here, so are you sure this is of essence?

Comment: @Dror There's precious little "nuance" in regard to which formula is correct. For example, when $p_1=p_2=\frac23,$ your formula says A has altogether a $\frac12$ probability to win. But $p_1=\frac23$ means A has a $\frac23$ probability to win _on the very first guess,_ so altogether A's probability to win must be at least that great.

Comment: @DavidK I take your word for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution #$1$:

Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ wins the game.

Then
$$p = p_1 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)p$$
Solve for $p$.

Explanation:

Either $A$ wins on the first question (probability $p_1$), or if not (probability $(1-p_1)$), then if $B$ *doesn't* win on his first question (probability $(1-p_2))$, player $A$ is effectively at the start of a brand new game, hence the probability of winning from that point is exactly $p$.

Solution #$2$:

$A$ wins on the first question with probability $p_1$.

$A$ wins on $A's$ second question with probability $(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_1$.

$A$ wins on $A's$ third question with probability $(1-p_1)^2(1-p_2)^2p_1$.

. . .

Thus, the probability that $A$ wins is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(r^n)p_1$$
where $r=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)$.

It's the sum of a geometric series. Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved considering just the first two rounds.

**Odds** in favor of $A = p_1 : (1-p_1)p_2$

Convert **odds** to **probability**, $Pr = \dfrac{p_1}{p_1+(1-p_1)p_2}$

$\underline{Added\; explanation}$

Probabilities for every subsequent two rounds will just get multiplied by some factor,
which means that the odds in favor (which is a ratio) remains unchanged